# java or php for developing database driven android app

Tags: java, php, android

I have an existing PHP MySQL web app that I want to make an android app for to look up account info, get status info for work orders, upload photos, etc.

I'm new to Android Dev and found a site phpforandroid.net that says I can use PHP to build android apps.  6 years ago I did a basic Java class n learned a little about Java, but not much.

I want to have a login to the app, then present a menu to drill further into heir account info.

My first choice would be PHP if the database interaction can happen, but I don't really know.  Anyone else gone down the PHP db driven route, or is Java the way I should go?  Any tutorials you would recommend?

What are the community thoughts?  THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you build a smartphone compatible website (i.e. with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/))? You could use your existing PHP knowledge *and* the app would run on any descent smartphone, not only Android.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I hadn't thought about that and didn't know about jquerymobile.  I really like the idea of a mobile-crossbrowser friendly app instead of where I was heading.  I read the jquerymobile website and think that might be a great way to go.  Would I simply create a subdomain like "mobile.mywebapp.com" and then create new web pages with the jquerymobile code under that domain, then have my webapp detect the device and redirect to that subdomain?

Comment: Yes, that would be a way. As for "detecting mobile device": There a plenty of snippets for this, i.e. http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Answer (score 1):

How about a mobile version of your web app? You could make it work on other phone platforms, you'd have full control over the code, instant updates without bothering the end user.